# Addressing Professor in email with half-typed name, how to deal with the mistake?

Tags: email, psychology

You address a new Professor by accident with half-typed name in an email. The professor is from US but working now as a professor in Europe. This was my mistake. Rest of the mail was done except half of the name -- the name had unique alphabets not finding in my keyboard so he may have similar experiences. Anyway my mistake can make me look very ignorant the expression I don't want to create.

*How should you deal with the issue? With apologies email? Just forgetting the mistake and in the next email making 100% sure to have correct spelling?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia.

Comment: Try [Professor 't Hooft's collection of spellings of his name](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/ap.html).

Comment: I see no point in closing this: manners, daily psychology and teaching them belong to academia -- thank you for your answers so far. I think it would be super cool to have more delicate analysis on email structures and word choices in other answers, details are important. Creating casual tune with just `Hi David, continuing with main topic -- hiding apologies to the latest perhaps best way with get-things-done-attitude without wasting too much time to the mistake.` instead of formal tune changing the situation more casual where mistakes are more understandable :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Forget about the mistake. If you want you can apologise in the next email. First names are more than enough for most academics unless you are culturally inclined to be very formal with a professor of the same back ground.

Comment: I feel like the OP is asking more about if they had addressed an email to you as "Professor Sae" and forgot to finish the name.

Comment: Thank you, I got an excellent connection with simple *"I apologise the mispelling"* and we had awesome meeting :)

Answer (score 8):

> How should you deal with the issue? With apologies email? Just forgetting the mistake and in the next email making 100% sure to have correct spelling?

Unless you have reasons to believe that the professor is in some way miffed (rather unlikely), you deal with this by laughing and moving on.